# Is there a way to do this Dynamic, Error safe XSL include / import in XSL?

Tags: xslt

I would like to have an xsl:include/import that will satisfy 2 requirements

1. **Error safe:** e.g. if the template doesn't exist, do nothing
2. **Dynamic:** e.g. the value of the included XSL is an value in the XML

e.g.

```
<xsl:import href="<xsl:value-of select='/root/@additionalFormattingXSL' />.xsl"/>
```

Is any way to get some or all of the above requirements? (no Java allowed) in any existing XSLT version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to perform the input yourself using an additional XSL stylesheet. This import-processing stylesheet takes your original stylesheet as input, and outputs an expanded stylesheet that contains the original one plus all the successfully imported stylesheets.

That way, you have complete control over requirements 1 and 2. Regarding requirement 1, you can use [doc-available()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-doc-available) in your import-processing stylesheet.

FYI, in general the way to incorporate dynamic values into an attribute value is to use an [Attribute Value Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates), e.g.

```
href="{/root/@additionalFormattingXSL}.xsl"
```

However this only works on attributes that are designated as AVTs, such as an attribute of a literal result element. I'm pretty sure this is **not** the case for the `href` attribute of `<xsl:import>`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to help you if you said what you were trying to achieve: then we could make a judgement whether the way you hope to achieve it is totally hare-brained or not.

Remember that xsl:import is a mechanism for constructing a program from various modules, and as in the majority of programming languages, XSLT programs are constructed and compiled before they start executing. So you certainly can't get a stylesheet to modify itself dynamically by treating xsl:import as if it were some kind of executable instruction. However, you can write a stylesheet whose effect is to create or modify *another* XSLT stylesheet, and that's something that often makes sense.